# Side menu bar that contains data from database

Tags: html, css, menu, archive

I have a database that looks like

```
INSERT INTO `function1`( `function_name`, `categori`, `reference_function`, `description`) VALUES ([value-1],[value-2],[value-3],[value-4],[value-5])
```

Now I want a Menu and Sub-menu system that would show the **function_name** as **Menu titles** Onclicked expands to show list of **categori** under it and their descriptions.i.e **description**..
I did try to solve but the css doesnt seem to be correct as the descriptions.i.e **description** does not show at the right adjacent side to the menu rather than it drops down.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
ul, #myUL {
  list-style-type: none;
}

#myUL {

  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.caret {
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-user-select: none; /* Safari 3.1+ */
  -moz-user-select: none; /* Firefox 2+ */
  -ms-user-select: none; /* IE 10+ */
  user-select: none;
}

.caret::before {
  content: "\27AF";
  color: black;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 6px;
  color:white;
}

.caret-down::before {
  -ms-transform: rotate(90deg); /* IE 9 */
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg); /* Safari */'
  transform: rotate(90deg); 
  color:white;
}
.tab {
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  width: 30%;
  height: 300px;
}

.tabcontent {
  padding: 0px 12px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  width: 70%;
  border-left: none;
}
.nested {
  display: none;
}

.active {
  display: block;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2 style="text-align: center">ARCHIVE SYSTEM</h2>
<p>Click on the arrow(s) to open or close the branches.</p>

<ul id="myUL">

    <?php 
$conn = mysqli_connect("XXXXX", "XXXXXX", "XXXXXX", "XXXXXXXX");

if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql_all ="SELECT * FROM function1 ";
$result_all = $conn->query($sql_all);
if ($result_all->num_rows > 0) {
    $sql ="SELECT function_name FROM function1 GROUP BY function_name";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
    {   $rowcat=$row['function_name'];
        echo"<li><span style=' display: block;
  background-color: green;
  color: white;
  padding: 15px 16px;
  width: 20%;
  outline: none;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  text-align: left;
  cursor: pointer;
  ' class='caret'>".$row['function_name']."</span>";

        $sql1="SELECT categori FROM function1 WHERE function_name='$rowcat' ";
        $result1 = $conn->query($sql1);

        echo" <ul class='nested'>";
        while($row1 = $result1->fetch_assoc())
        {  $rowcat1=$row1['categori'];


           echo"<li><span style=' display: block;
  background-color: green;
  color: white;
  padding: 15px 16px;
  width: 15%;
  outline: none;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  text-align: left;
  cursor: pointer;
  ' class='caret'>".$row1['categori']."</span>";

             $sql2="SELECT description,reference_function FROM function1 WHERE categori='$rowcat1'";
             $result2 = $conn->query($sql2);

             echo" <ul class='nested'>";
             while($row2 = $result2->fetch_assoc())
              {echo"<li><p style='width:500px;
  border: 1px solid #c3c3c3;
  display: flex;
  margin-left:30px;
  flex-wrap: wrap;'>".$row2['description'] ." references are --- ".$row2['reference_function']."</textarea>";
                }
           echo"</ul>";
        }
        echo"</ul>";
    }

} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();

?>

<script>
var toggler = document.getElementsByClassName("caret");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < toggler.length; i++) {
  toggler[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.parentElement.querySelector(".nested").classList.toggle("active");
    this.classList.toggle("caret-down");
  });
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Please help me to make it!!!

Comment: Firs of all, I will suggest you to make our code more organize and clean by adding your DB connection and SQL stamens in a separe file, then just displaying the result in your front end. Plus, creating CSS classes instead of adding inline style will help you to reduce your code. Once you make those changes will be easier to find a solution.

Comment: Thanks sir for the suggestion i would take care of it .... i jsut gave the whole code inorder to make fellow mates understand the code iam working on if you have a solution for a dynamic side menubar which which can display my database content please feel free to help me with it. Thank You